# How to use include script in vf page?

Tags: visualforce

i have my script code in a `JavaScript` `static resource` file.

My static resource file name is "`web2caseresources`" . In that, it has folders like

`web2case`-->`js`-->`filename.js`..

How do i need to refer this in my VF page using include `script` tag.

Comment: HI, can you post your current code to show us what you have tried and what error message you are getting with it ?

Answer (score 2):

For your example it would be:

```
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseresources, 'web2case/js/filename.js')}"></script>
```

The [URLFOR documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) explains that:

> This can be used to return a reference to a file contained in a static
>   resource archive (such as a .zip or .jar file). {!URLFOR(resource,
>   path)} Replace resource with the name of the static resource archive
>   expressed as a merge variable (for example, $Resource.resourceName),
>   and path with the local path to the file in the archive that you want
>   to reference.

Comment: Ya i have tried this and it worked for me . Now i have tried like " <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.web2caseresources, 'web2case/js/filename.js}" />

This is not working for me

Comment: Update static resource with other format. Ex rar to zip (or) zip to rar

Comment: @user23982 You need to be very careful that you haven't added e.g. an extra folder at the root of the ZIP file. And that the archive format is indeed ZIP. Also check that the content type of the static resource is "application/zip" (which it will be if the file you uploaded had a .zip extension).